# Making eyes in characters

Tags: bones

I am making an animal and I would to know if the eyes is in include in same object or is two objects that we have to parent it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter either way. If they are parented to the same armature, they can either be left separate or you can join them to the main mesh. The eye vertices need to be weighted properly, only to the eye bones.